# <%# %> and DataBind on UserControls

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have a `System.UI.Web.Page` that includes a `user control`.
I want to pass a variable from the `page to the user control`.
From what I can see, I have to use `<%# variable %>` and `DataBind()`, apparently.

But I can't find any clear examples that show how this is done.

Usually, when I use the User Control, it looks like:

```
<UI:YouTube VideoId="XXXXXXXX" runat="server" />
```

However, for this example it will look like:

```
<UI:YouTube VideoId="<%# sYouTubeCode %>" runat="server" />
```

sYouTubeCode is a `public string property` in the code behind of the page.

The `aspx page` has `AutoEventWireup="false"` when referencing the code behind, if that is relevant.

When do I do this `databinding`? 
In the Page or in the User Control, and what does it look like?

Comment: Been a few weeks since I've even looked at some WebForms.. but can't you do this from the code-behind? `youtubeControl.VideoId = sYouTubeCode;`?

Comment: I could try that, but I'd rather know how to use <%# %> properly, at least for simple properties of a Page.

Comment: I don't think it has to be the databind tag `<%#`, because you're not using a databinder. What if you simply use `<%=` ?

Comment: You can't use <%= %> when passing arguments to a user control.

Comment: Indeed. I just just fire up VS and try that. Apologies (it's been a while since I've actively done any WebForms)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example that I think illustrates what you are trying to accomplish. Please note that everything in the `<script runat="server">` tag could go in the codebehind, I just put them all in one file here to make it easier to read.

Since you have `AutoEventWireup` set to `false`, you'll need to override the `OnInit` method and wire up the `Load` event handler. In the `Page_Load` method, you can set the value of your property to whatever you want (I used the `MyText` property), and then just call `DataBind` on the server control (in this case I used a `Literal` control).

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" %>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Literal ID="litText" Text="<%# MyText %>" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script runat="server">
    public string MyText { get; set; }

    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            MyText = "some text to databind!";
            litText.DataBind();        
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        Load += Page_Load;
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
</script>
```

FWIW, while the code above works fine, I do think it is cleaner to just set the property in the `Page_Load` method, and then forgo the `<%# %>` in the front page. I feel that setting the property in the codebehind is the more common approach, but obviously the choice is up to you.

Also, in case you are interested, more information on `AutoEventWireup="false"` can be [found on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324151). Look for the section titled "When the value of the AutoEventWireup attribute is false".

**EDIT**

Static properties work fine too. Here's an example, using `Page.DataBind()` as @nunespascal suggested (it also works with `litText.DataBind()`).

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" %>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Literal ID="litText" Text="<%# MyClass.StaticProp %>" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script runat="server">
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            Page.DataBind();
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        Load += Page_Load;
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public static string StaticProp { get { return "Static Property"; } }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How about if the value for Text is not a property from the Page, but is a static method or property from a class included in the .aspx file itself? i.e. `<%# MyClass.StaticMethod() %>`.  I know it's not a part of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you are calling `DataBind` on the page, feel free to pass values to your user control like `VideoId="<%# sYouTubeCode %>"`.

You should receive your values just fine.

Note that DataBinding does happen late in the life cycle. Just before PreRender.

Calling `DataBind` on the page will call it for call controls on the page. Calling it on Page_Load should be good.